# Custom shape request in Locust

Tags: python, load, locust

I am using Locust for our load test and we have some issues. We want control sending request in milliseconds with an exponential distribution. As far as I searched, I found out that Locust works within seconds and we couldn't say that we sent one request in 12ms and the next request in 59ms. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Locust, but I can see that it supports defining custom wait_times between iterations.
You may override the wait_time method by something like this in your User class:

```
 def wait_time(self):
```